# SWIFT Segment Controlled UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

My code is shown below. It's derived from a YouTube video made 3 years ago. Since the date the video was posted, Swift has updated and the output of the function which is `Anchor` can no longer be found in scope. I'd like to ask for helping in finding a replacement for the output.

```
extension UIView {
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,
                bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding:
                UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> Anchor {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()
    
        if let top = top {
            anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top,
                                                           constant: padding.top)
        }
    
        if let leading = leading {
            anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
                                                                    leading, constant: padding.left)
        }
    
        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint (equalTo:
                                                                    bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
        }
    
        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:
                                    size.width).isActive = true
        }
        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:
                                        size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's way too much code missing. `Anchor` and `AnchoredConstraints` are not, and have never been Apple-provided classes. Where's the rest of this function?

Answer (score 0):

I can't suppose your real intention but I believe this snippet(in Swift 5) may be what are you looking for

```swift
extension UIView {
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,
                bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding:
                UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top).isActive = true
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing).isActive = true
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }

        layoutMargins = padding
    }
}
```

The following is a playground sample code showing how can you use it. (Please don't forget to include the extension somewhere in the code below if you get it try)

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.backgroundColor = .gray

        view.addSubview(label)

        label.anchor(
            top: view.topAnchor,
            leading: view.leadingAnchor,
            bottom: view.bottomAnchor,
            trailing: view.trailingAnchor
        )
        
        self.view = view
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

That's the best I can do to help you with no more information, so please in a next post try to give more details about the intentions of the code.

In addition I would advise you that there are better solutions for pinning views in layout nowadays, then I believe it worths a quick research for alternatives.

I Hope it can be of some help to you.